# Duvida construção QUERY SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho duas tabelas TB1 e TB2 com campos iguais a fim de ser comparado os registros.

A lógica é: Consultar os registros contidos em TB1, mas não contido TB2, considerando 3 campos: codigo, data e valor. Pois o codigo pode se repetir mas data e valor variam, logo preciso comparar o registro como um todo.

Logo:

```
SELECT CODIGO, DATA, VALOR
FROM TB1
EXCEPT
SELECT CODIGO, DATA, VALOR
FROM TB2
```

Porém, eu preciso criar uma condição/cláusula para que ele não retorne os registros cujo a diferença de valor seja = 1

```
TAB1:
Codigo: 001 Data: 02/02/2019 Valor: 224

TAB2:

Codigo: 001  Data: 02/02/2019 Valor: 223


Resultado: Não deve retornar nenhum registro. Pois 224 - 223 = 1.
```

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   WITH CTE AS
 (
  SELECT TAB1.CODIGO,
   TAB1.DATA,
   TAB1.VALOR,
   TAB2.VALOR,
   (TAB1.VALOR - TAB2.VALOR) AS DIFERENCA
 FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN TAB2 
        ON TAB1.CODIGO = TAB2.CODIGO
 )
SELECT * FROM CTE 
    WHERE DIFERENCA <1;
```

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte Crie uma CTE e depois aplique a checagem da diferença

Comment: @rbz ele menciona que não deseja os registros, cuja a diferença é = 1

Comment: Não considerei isso, foi uma sugestão ao Guilherme. Sobre criar uma CTE, acredito que fica mais "didático" para ele entender a lógica.

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta a minha pergunta sobre a query

Answer (score 0):

Veja se atende:

```
SELECT TB1.CODIGO, TB1.DATA, TB1.VALOR
FROM TB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TB2 ON (TB1.CODIGO = TB2.CODIGO AND TB1.DATA =  TB2.DATA)
WHERE TB2.CODIGO IS NULL OR TB2.DATA IS NULL OR TB2.VALOR IS NULL OR (ABS(TB1.VALOR-TB2.VALOR) <> 1);
```

======================================

Pelos testes que fiz com os dados fornecidos parece ser:

```
SELECT tab1.codigo, tab1.datap, tab1.valor
FROM tab1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tab2 WHERE (tab1.codigo = tab2.codigo AND tab1.datap = tab2.datap AND ABS(tab1.valor - tab2.valor) = 1));
```

Comment: Neste caso use: `(ABS(TB1.VALOR-TB2.VALOR) <> 1)`.

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta contendo o resultado

Answer (score 0):

#### Atualização

Pela sua nova explicação, a resposta mais perto seria do "anonimo".
Eu faria apenas um ajuste, mas ficaria a mesma coisa:

```
SELECT A.CODIGO, A.DATAP, A.VALOR 
FROM TB1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB2 B ON (B.CODIGO = A.CODIGO AND B.DATAP = A.DATAP)
WHERE ((B.CODIGO OR B.DATAP OR B.VALOR) IS NULL) OR ABS(B.VALOR - A.VALOR) <> 1
```

#### Veja funcionando: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s3PvFhTNkjtSG8YCcgka4w/0)

---

Vou fazer de uma outra forma aos demais para ter mais opções e até as vezes te ajude a entender melhor.

```
SELECT A.CODIGO, A.DATA, A.VALOR
FROM TB2 B
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TB1 A ON (A.CODIGO = B.CODIGO AND A.DATA =  B.DATA)
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB1) OR ABS(B.VALOR - A.VALOR) <> 1)
```

Eu não testei, então caso houver algo errado, comente.

---

[Uma breve explicação sobre Inner, Left, Right, Outer/Full e Cross Join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/92908)

[EXISTS / NOT EXISTS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[ABS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta contendo a saida

Answer (score 0):

Acho que minha Query venha a ser mais complexa do que parece. Para todas as instruçôes SQL que me mandaram

Fiz 2 registros em cada tabela:

```
Tab1:
codigo  datap   valor
001 10/10/2010  800
001 10/10/2010  1000

Tab2:

codigo  datap   valor
001   10/10/2010    801
001   10/10/2010    999
```

Ele retornou:

```
codigo  datap   valor
001 10/10/2010  801
001 10/10/2010  999
```

Não poderia ter retornado nada, já que eu quero somente os registros que estão em TB1 mas naõ estao em TB2

Para os senhores compreenderme melhor:

Eu desejo os registros que estão em TAB1, mas não estão em TAB2.

Logo, imagine o seguinte registro:

```
Tab1:
codigo  datap   valor
001 10/10/2010  800
001 10/10/2010  900
001 10/10/2010  700


Tab2:

codigo  datap   valor
001   10/10/2010    801
001   10/10/2010.   950
001   10/10/2010.   701
```

Logo o correto seria exibir o registro da TAB1, visto que está em TAB1, mas não está em TAB2 (campo VALOR divergente).

Porém, eu quero excluir dessa condição o campo VALOR cuja a diferença entre eles é 1.

Logo, para os registros acima, a saída esperada é:

```
001 10/10/2010  900
```

Explicação:
Em TB1 temos 800, porém em TB2 temos 801. Diferença de 1.

A mesma coisa para o 700.

Comment: Guilherme, se há divergências com todas as respostas, então há erros na descrição de sua pergunta. A sua query parece ser bem simples e básica. Você deve editar a sua pergunta, explicar melhor, exemplificar melhor com "cenário atual x resultado desejado" (melhor colocar ainda no [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)), colocar a tag de qual é o seu banco de dados, e todos outros possíveis detalhes. Assim podemos analisar melhor seu caso.

Comment: Peço sinceras desculpas se não fui Claro na descrição. Na minha resposta, adicionei maiores detalhes.